# Jquery script showing conditional fields onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that I need to add some conditional fields. Here is a link to it on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2Ab2/59/#&togetherjs=ap7ooRf0rw

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('input[name="Payer Type"]').change(function () {
        var val1 = $("input[name='Payer Type']:checked").val();
        if (val1 == "Medicare") {
$("#Medicare_num").show("slow");
        } else {
$("#Medicare_num").hide("slow");        }

});

$('input[name="Payer Type"]').change(function () {
        var val1 = $("input[name='Payer Type']:checked").val();
        if (val1 == "Medicaid") {
$("#Medicaid_num").show("slow");
        } else {
$("#Medicaid_num").hide("slow");        }

});

//
$('input[name="Payer Type"]').change(function () {
        var val1 = $("input[name='Payer Type']:checked").val();
        if (val1 == "Commercial Insurance") {
$("#Comm_name, #Comm_policy_num").show("slow");
        } else {
$("#Comm_name, #Comm_policy_num").hide("slow");
        }
});


//

});
</script>
```

```html
<form>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 750px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 381px;">Please Select Payer Type:</td>
        <td colspan="3" style="width: 340px;">
          <input name="Payer Type" type="checkbox" value="Medicare" />Medicare&nbsp;
          <input name="Payer Type" type="checkbox" value="Medicaid" />Medicaid&nbsp;
          <input name="Payer Type" type="checkbox" value="Commercial Insurance" />Commercial Insurance</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 381px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3" style="width: 340px;">
          <input id="Medicare_num" name="Medicare Num" placeholder="Medicare ID#" type="text" />
          <input id="Medicaid_num" name="Medicaid Number" placeholder="Medicaid ID #" type="text" />
          <input id="Comm_name" name="Commercial Insurance Name" placeholder="Commercial Insurance Name" size="50" type="text" />
          <input id="Comm_policy_num" name="Commercial Insurance Number" placeholder="Policy #" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Now, I have it working except for one thing: All the conditional text fields show right away. I want it to show only if the checkboxes are selected.

Answer (score 0):

First you should give the checkboxes different names, at the moment you cannot differentiate between them because they all have the same name/id, after that you can see if a checkbox is checked:

```
if $('#' + id).is(":checked") {
    //show textbox
}
```

Being `id` 'medicare' or whatever the id of the checkbox is. Run that `if` statement on load and then it will only display the textbox if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: @dccreatives : this answer is not mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind a single change event handler and toggle by selecting element using [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // bind event handler to the checkbox
  $('input[name="Payer Type"]').change(function() {
    // get input element where name attribute is starts with the checkbox value
    // and then toggle the visibility based on the checked property
    $('input[name^="' + this.value + '"]').toggle(this.checked);
    // trigger the change event 
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 750px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 381px;">Please Select Payer Type:</td>
        <td colspan="3" style="width: 340px;">
          <input name="Payer Type" type="checkbox" value="Medicare" />Medicare&nbsp;
          <input name="Payer Type" type="checkbox" value="Medicaid" />Medicaid&nbsp;
          <input name="Payer Type" type="checkbox" value="Commercial Insurance" />Commercial Insurance</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 381px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3" style="width: 340px;">
          <input id="Medicare_num" name="Medicare Num" placeholder="Medicare ID#" type="text" />
          <input id="Medicaid_num" name="Medicaid Number" placeholder="Medicaid ID #" type="text" />
          <input id="Comm_name" name="Commercial Insurance Name" placeholder="Commercial Insurance Name" size="50" type="text" />
          <input id="Comm_policy_num" name="Commercial Insurance Number" placeholder="Policy #" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```